# Submit to Google Spreadsheet browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have created an html form that submits to a google spreadsheet and works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but on explorer is failing somehow - I believe it relates to explorer not playing well with "fetch". How can I get explorer to cooperate? This is an attempt from this blog:

https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175

```
<script>
function sendData()
{
    var scriptURL ='https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwqWPFTTEbhUdVEwLsonLGnAvDTwgTYyfmdYl_tjJ.../exec';
    var form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet'];
    fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of cross-browser compatibility. You'll need to add code to check for errors and handle them in specific manners for the various browsers you need to support. Note that "is failing somehow" is not a valid problem description - you should include exact error messages, and how you have attempted to resolve them, in your question.